# Uploading and converting images to a format Flash can work with

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Preface: I am 100% new to the Flash and ActionScript world, doing research for a potential project.

Is it realistic to design a tool that could import a number of raster and vector formats, then convert them to a medium that can be used by a Flash application? Practically speaking, I'm looking into designing a Flash web application that lets users upload files (particularly in vector) and manipulate them on-screen (for now, just moving them around, nothing crazy).

A fair amount of the problem is converting from the specific vector format into the desired format. My question is really this: what is the format I should be attempting to convert them into for manipulation in my application? These files do not need to be redownloaded - they go up, get converted, get translated into a byte array, then stuck in a database for retrieval.

Ideally I would do conversion on the Flash application, depending on how easy it end up being. That said, also looking into doing it on the web-service end that sticks it in a database (in whatever language I choose to power that).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pretty much everything with raster images, but vectors will be a problem. There's a SVG library (http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/) that will do for basic stuff. As for other vector formats... well, you'd have to write your own parsers.

Comment: Agreed, the best option I can think of is to use a server side script that can handle many file types and convert them all to something Flash can easily work with, likely a raster format.  Alternatively as stated you'd probably want to write your own parser if you were going to try and translate directly to the graphics draw methods, however SVG doesn't map 1:1 to their draw methods which is basically why they made up FXG.  I like this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was hoping a magic library existed already...c'est la vie.

Answer (score 1):

Why SWF format itself isn't an option? That would be much easier to implement, given you already have the player in place. SWF is a good vector graphics format, I am not that much familiar with SVG, but my brief experience lets me say that SWF is, at least, not worse then SVG in many aspects, and, possibly often times is better (it is naturally compressed, unlike SVG for example).

There aren't many free tools that would let you manipulate the SWF files by means of a graphic editor, but if your SWF contains nothing but graphics, spare few exceptions, GNash can display it fairly well, there's also HXswfMl project that allows compiling SWFs from their XML description. But given you yourself want to make one such editor, I don't think that would be your problem.